# How to Read Voltage Level?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, programming, analogread, digital-analog-conversion

I want to read voltage level by my Arduino board please help in this regard. I am using this syntax.

```
volts = analogRead(A3);    // read the input pin
Serial.println(volts)
```

Comment: Show where and how in your code you declare `volts`, and how are you wiring the voltage you want to read to the analog input.

Comment: Also, in what way is this not working?

Comment: Other than missing the semicolon on the end of the second line, this chunk of code will work. Can you please show your whole program?

Comment: Note that instead of printing out the number of volts on the input, it will output an ADC count that stands for some number of volts; by default, 1024/5 counts per volt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//use this syntax and add ; sign at end of each line and try to read voltage level via voltage divider circuit.

```
volts = analogRead(A3);    // read the input pin
Serial.println(volts);             // debug value
```

Answer (score 1):

First off you need to convert your signal's units from analog -> voltage. Do this by using the following equation. I've modified your code so you can copy and paste it into your IDE.

```
float volts = analogRead(A3) * ( 5.0 / 1024.0) ;
```

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Your first solution will always be 0. `5 / 1024` does integer division which always results in 0. Any number multiplied with 0 is then 0.

Comment: @gre_gor I stand corrected! Good catch. I completely forgot about that. :)